# Count how many times each value until it changes - excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to count how many times is each value repeated until the value changes.

```
A B
1 3
1 3
1 3
3 1
4 1
5 4
5 4
5 4
5 4
1 2
1 2
```

so like column A are the values and B is the number of times the value appeared until it changed

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you have already tried something, please post it, otherwise this question is likely to be closed due to lack of work from your side.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a possible solution but with 2 Formulas. One for first cell and another for remaining cells.

See below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Remember that the formula refers to one extra cell in the end. I.e. if the data is in A1:A15, formula needs to refer to A1:A16. One cell extra beneath the range should be blank and free for this code to work.

in B1 enter

```
=MATCH(9^99,IF(A1:$A$16=A1,0,9^99),0)-1
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar to create an Array Formula. The formula will automatically enclose itself in curly braces. Without this step it won't work correctly.

In B2 enter

```
=IF(A2=A1,B1,MATCH(9^99,IF(A2:$A$16=A2,0,9^99),0)-1)
```

Again create an Array Formula <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and drag it down upto intended rows.

A better solution with single formula may be possible. Wait for others to respond on this question.

---

**Edit 1**

If you leave one cell above your list as a header, then a single array formula will work.

See below screenshot.

```
=IF(A2=A1,B1,MATCH(9^99,IF(A2:$A$17=A2,0,9^99),0)-1)
```

[image]